# Application:openFiles: separate files by groups

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I need that my application detect how many files has been dropped to it dock icon. For this i use application:openFiles: method

```
- (void)application:(NSApplication *)sender openFiles:(NSArray *)filenames
{
  NSLog(@"%d",[filenames count]);
}
```

But unfortunately files sometimes separates by group. So, for example i dragged 3 files to dock icon and get this output:

```
2
1
```

How could it be?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately that's life. If you really need to count the number of files received in a drop to the Dock icon, you need to set up a timer to combine the results received by the call `application:openFiles:` within a second (or some appropriate length of time.)