# Dragged files on a Cocoa application icon - file types

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to get all dragged files name and it works, but if i multiple drag

**zip file + image** at the same time my code only output the zip file:

```
- (BOOL)application:(NSApplication *)theApplication openFile:(NSString *)filename
{
    return [self processFile:filename];
}

- (BOOL)processFile:(NSString *)file
{
    NSLog(@"The following file has been dropped or selected: %@",file);
    // Process file here
    return  YES; // Return YES when file processed succesfull, else return NO.
}
```

**Info.plist:**

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.data</string>
                <string>public.content</string>
                <string>public.image</string>
                <string>public.directory</string>
                <string>public.item</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

But if i drag zip file + xml file it output both. How can i accept any file type and allow multiple drag of zip file and image at same time??

**THIS HAPPENS ONLY IF THE ZIP CONTAIN " Cyberduck " EXECUTABLE FILE**

Comment: Does it work to override `-application:openFiles:` instead of `-application:openFile:`?

Comment: No, the same happens :(

Answer (score 1):

As @charles-srstka says you need to implement ["application:openFile**s**:" delegate method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplicationdelegate/1428742-application?language=objc) . Beware of a caveat though that you might still receive zip and image one by one, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664240/applicationopenfiles-separate-files-by-groups).

Comment: It only happens if the zip contain a program

Comment: happens only if the program inside zip is Cyberduck

Comment: it try to start the program, how to not do that?? i just want the path and name...

Comment: It... tries to start the program? Isn't your program already running?

Comment: I meant the executable insize the zip